# Problems with assembly OSM

Tags: openstreetmap

**Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

```
basil@debian:/$ sudo renderd -f -c /usr/local/etc/renderd.conf
[sudo] password for basil:
renderd[8219]: Rendering daemon started
renderd[8219]: Initiating reqyest_queue
renderd[8219]: Parsing section renderd
renderd[8219]: Parsing render section 0
renderd[8219]: Parsing section mapnik
renderd[8219]: Parsing section default
renderd[8219]: config renderd: unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[8219]: config renderd: num_threads=4
renderd[8219]: config renderd: num_slaves=0
renderd[8219]: config renderd: tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: config renderd: stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[8219]: config mapnik:  plugins_dir=/usr/local/lib/mapnik/input
renderd[8219]: config mapnik:  font_dir=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu
renderd[8219]: config mapnik:  font_dir_recurse=1
renderd[8219]: config renderd(0): Active
renderd[8219]: config renderd(0): unix socketname=/var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[8219]: config renderd(0): num_threads=4
renderd[8219]: config renderd(0): tile_dir=/var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: config renderd(0): stats_file=/var/run/renderd/renderd.stats
renderd[8219]: config map 0:   name(default) file(/home/basil/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml) uri(/osm_tiles/) htcp() host(localhost)
renderd[8219]: Initialising unix server socket on /var/run/renderd/renderd.sock
renderd[8219]: Created server socket 4
renderd[8219]: Renderd is using mapnik version 2.0.3
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Italic.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-Bold.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerifCondensed-BoldItalic.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique.ttf
renderd[8219]: DEBUG: Loading font: /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSerif.ttf
Running in foreground mode...
renderd[8219]: Starting stats thread
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: Loading parameterization function for
debug: init_storage_backend: initialising file storage backend at: /var/lib/mod_tile
renderd[8219]: Loading parameterization function for
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
renderd[8219]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6.9357733912442328e-310"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9357733912442328e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9357733912442328e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/basil/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[8219]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'defaul`enter code here`t': :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6.9357767068626562e-310"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9357767068626562e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9357767068626562e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/basil/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
Postgis Plugin: SRID warning, using srid=-1
renderd[8219]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6.9357833380995029e-310"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9357833380995029e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9357833380995029e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/basil/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
renderd[8219]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6.9357800224810796e-310"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9357800224810796e-310 LIMIT 0
                      ^
Full sql was: 'SELECT * FROM 6.9357800224810796e-310 LIMIT 0'
 (encountered during parsing of layer 'landcover' in map '/home/basil/src/mapnik-style/osm.xml')
```

================
what could it be?
renderd[8219]: An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "6.9357733912442328e-310"
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM 6.9357733912442328e-310 LIMIT 0

can not quite build this system
what could be the problem?

Thanks for the help

Comment: can error while loading data? how to fix this error?

Comment: It would be the best to ask at the #osm IRC channel in the OFTC network. And please post the solution here afterwards.